# Grails Run-app Error - Failed to create sessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I was upgrading Grails project from 1.3.4 to 2.3.7 , fixed most of the plugin-related issues and compiled successfully. But while running the application I get below exception

> Message: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Looks like this is related to hibernate, I have tried different version of hibernate ( 3.6.9, 3.6.10, 4, etc) but did not work. This error occurs irrespective DB (hdb/mysql)

```
  plugins {
    compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.2"
        //compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
        compile ":webflow:2.0.8.1"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.10"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
    }
```

Any hints would be really helpful, details error stack is below

```
|Running Grails application
Loading configuration files from classpath
ActiveMQ Embedded...
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Error |
2014-05-01 23:54:47,341 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator  - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to perform post initialization config: file:./grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml
Message: org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory
   Line | Method
->>  59 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   305 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   246 | loadClass in     ''
|   303 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . in     ''
^   662 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2014-05-01 23:54:54,670 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by StackOverflowError: null
->> 905 | fromCacheOrNew in org.h2.util.StringUtils
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   2921 | read     in org.h2.command.Parser
|   2516 | readTerm in     ''
|   2078 | readFactor in     ''
|   2065 | readSum  in     ''
|   2038 | readConcat in     ''
|   1903 | readCondition in     ''
|   1876 | readAnd  in     ''
|   1868 | readExpression in     ''
|   1781 | parseSelectSimpleSelectPart in     ''
|   1813 | parseSelectSimple in     ''
|   1707 | parseSelectSub in     ''
|   1550 | parseSelectUnion in     ''
|   1538 | parseSelect in     ''
|   405 | parsePrepared in     ''
|   279 | parse    in     ''
|   251 | parse .  in     ''
|   218 | prepareCommand in     ''
|   428 | prepareLocal in org.h2.engine.Session
|   377 | prepareCommand in     ''
|   1138 | prepareCommand in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection
|    72 | executeQuery in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement
|    73 | activeCheckConnection in com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester
|   374 | testPooledConnection in com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager
|   237 | refurbishResourceOnCheckout in     ''
|   1579 | attemptRefurbishResourceOnCheckout in com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool
|   479 | checkoutResource in     ''
|   514 | checkoutResource in     ''
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: How does `BuildConfig` look like?

Comment: build.config is quite huge , which part are you looking for? Hibernate/Spring

Comment: The whole file, mainly `grails.project.dependency.resolution`, but having the file itself will be good. You can paste it in pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4cY119Fz ,thanks